# same blog post link appearing in different tag pages

Tags: seo, tags

I have each blog post tagged with different terms. Each term page lists the tagged post link, so that the link may appear more than once. How does that affect my SEO?

Comment: The post is displayed in its entirety on the term page, not simply an intro? Multiple posts are displayed on that page?

Comment: just the links, like: tag 1: post 1, post 2. tag2: post 1, post 4.

Comment: If the posts are just linked and not repeated in their entirety on different pages then I can't see it being a problem. (As @milo5b states in his answer.) Although your question title is misleading if this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any page that looks too similar one to another it won't affect your SEO. However, if more than one URL have the same (or close enough) content, you might have duplicate content issues.